How can i do the following partial decomposition?
I need to prove that:
$$
\frac{1}{(x-a)(x-b)} = \frac{1}{(b-a)(x-b)}- \frac{1}{(b-a)(x-a)},
$$
and I must note that I need to go from the left expression to the right (because of the exercise).
So, I tried to solve
$$
\frac{1}{(x-a)(x-b)} = \frac{C}{(x-a)} + \frac{D}{(x-b)}.
$$
Unfortunately, from there, I am reaching a system that I can not solve. I get $C + D = 0$ and $Cb = -Da + 1$. From here I am not being able to make any progress. Any suggestions?

Hint: clear fractions and use the cover-up method.

I think you're mixing up $C$ and $D$ with $A$ and $B$ and also $A$ and $B$ with $a$ and $b$. You've obtained two linear equations in the variables $C$ and $D$, and the usual methods for solving them should work here. (What would you do if $a$ and $b$ were numbers rather than letters?)

yes, sorry, i forgot to put C and D instead of A and B, respectively. But still, i am getting to those two equations and i haven't been able to make any progress.

@SeanRoberson i will look into that method, never heard of it

Multiply both sides by $x-a$, then let $x=a$ to get $C$. Multiply both sides by $x-b$, then let $x=b$ to get $D$.

@GregMartin looking better at the equations in fact i have been able to do it that way(and by other suggested ways)

Take the $\frac{1}{(x-a)(x-b)}$ to the other side and bring $\frac{1}{(b-a)(x-b)}$ to the LHS

Another possible approach (under the assumption that $a\neq b$):
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{(x - a)(x - b)} & = \frac{1}{b - a}\frac{b - a}{(x - a)(x - b)}\\\\
& = \frac{1}{b - a}\frac{(x - a) - (x - b)}{(x - a)(x - b)}\\\\
& = \frac{1}{b - a}\left(\frac{1}{x - b} - \frac{1}{x - a}\right)\\\\
& = \frac{1}{(b - a)(x - b)} - \frac{1}{(b - a)(x - a)}
\end{align*}

Lets continue from what you found:
$\begin{cases}C+D=0\Rightarrow C=-D\\Cb=-Da+1\Rightarrow D(a-b)=1\end{cases}$
From second equation we get:
$D=\frac1{a-b}=-\frac 1{b-a}\Rightarrow C=\frac 1{b-a}$
Putting C and D in relation you get:
$$\frac1{(x-a)(x-b)}=\frac1{(b-a)(x-b)}-\frac1{(b-a)(x-a)}$$
